# How can I analyze C # in sonar?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

I have installed and running:

- sonarqube-5.1
- sonar-runner-dist-2.4
- mysql 5.1.63
- jdk 1.7.0_79

In Ubuntu 11.04 (32 bits).

It's only analyzing the Java code.
How can I do to also read the C # that I have included in the same project?
What do I need to do or add?

Thanks!

Comment: What plugins did you install? Also consider to upgrade to SonarQube 5.6 LTS.

Comment: I have not installed any plugin. Unfortunately I can't upgrade to SonarQube 5.6. What plugin should I install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install the C# plugin and the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild.
See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/C%23+Plugin

Comment: Is there any C# plugin for SonarQube 5.1?

Comment: Open Settings > System > Update Center > Available Plugins and you will get your answer for the C# plugin (answer is yes :-) )

Comment: Simon Brandhof. Thank you very much for your reply. With these indications I managed to analyze the C #.